# Lucene.NET ObjectDisposedException when searching

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I have an application that uses Lucene.Net for searching.
There is a windows service that builds the index, and a ASP.NET application then creates an IndexSearcher to search the index.

Now I am constantly getting the following stack trace/error when attempting to do a search.  I can't debug it because it is deployed on production.

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a closed file.
 at System.IO.__Error.FileNotOpen()
 at System.IO.FileStream.Seek(Int64 offset, SeekOrigin origin)
 at Lucene.Net.Store.SimpleFSDirectory.SimpleFSIndexInput.ReadInternal(Byte[] b, Int32 offset, Int32 len)
 at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.ReadBytes(Byte[] b, Int32 offset, Int32 len, Boolean useBuffer)
 at Lucene.Net.Index.CompoundFileReader.CSIndexInput.ReadInternal(Byte[] b, Int32 offset, Int32 len)
 at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.Refill()
 at Lucene.Net.Store.BufferedIndexInput.ReadByte()
 at Lucene.Net.Store.IndexInput.ReadVInt()
 at Lucene.Net.Index.TermBuffer.Read(IndexInput input, FieldInfos fieldInfos) 
 at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentTermEnum.Next()
 at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentTermEnum.ScanTo(Term term) 
 at Lucene.Net.Index.TermInfosReader.Get(Term term, Boolean useCache) 
 at Lucene.Net.Index.TermInfosReader.Terms(Term term) 
 at Lucene.Net.Index.SegmentReader.Terms(Term t) 
 at Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.MultiTermEnum..ctor(IndexReader topReader, IndexReader[] readers, Int32[] starts, Term t) 
 at Lucene.Net.Index.DirectoryReader.Terms(Term term) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardTermEnum..ctor(IndexReader reader, Term term) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardQuery.GetEnum(IndexReader reader) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.MultiTermQuery.ConstantScoreAutoRewrite.Rewrite(IndexReader reader, MultiTermQuery query) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.MultiTermQuery.Rewrite(IndexReader reader) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.WildcardQuery.Rewrite(IndexReader reader) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.BooleanQuery.Rewrite(IndexReader reader) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.IndexSearcher.Rewrite(Query original) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.Query.Weight(Searcher searcher) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.CreateWeight(Query query) 
 at Lucene.Net.Search.Searcher.Search(Query query, Filter filter, Int32 n, Sort sort)
```

Comment: More Info:  I think it was a result of trying to open an index that crashed before it could be created completely.

Comment: a long time has elapsed since you asked this question. Did you ever find the cause for the problem?

Comment: Basically it was trying to search an index that was never completed.  I guess the indexing process crashed before it was finished.

Comment: A common problem is caused by continually creating the IndexWriter whenever new docs are to be added. Depending on how that done and if it can happen via multiple threads, the IW ctor will probably get confused by the files being in an intermediate state and just zap the index.
Just keep a single instance of the IW. Operations on the IW (delete, update etc) are threadsafe.
Do searches by creating the searcher with "searcher = new IndexSearcher(writer.GetReader())" (there are many perf nuances here, but this is the simple case)